# sonarqube 5.6.4- break build in preview mode

Tags: sonarqube, preview

I have just upgraded sonar to 5.6.4 and I want break my build through build breaker or any other way in preview mode? I checked in preview mode report-task.txt is not getting generated while in publish mode it is, can some suggest?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible.

BuildBreaker looks at the project's Quality Gate status. The Quality Gate is only updated on the server side, after the analysis report submitted to the server has been processed. Preview mode does not submit an analysis report to the server (kinda the point), so there will be no Quality Gate update.

Comment: I was able to break the build in preview mode.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be nice to have the ability to check the quality gate result in an ephemeral/temporary sense as to integrate with Jenkins branch builds.